# Fire click event in file input ionic 3 android

Tags: javascript, android, html, angular, ionic3

I'm working on Ionic 3 project and users can upload multiple images using the application. I want to open the file browser when click on a **Button** like bellow. This is the code sample I'm working on

**home.ts**

```
public openBrowser() {
  const fileLoader = document
    .getElementById('fileUploader') as HTMLElement;
  fileLoader.click();  
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <input type="file" [hidden]="true" id="fileUploader" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" (change)="onChangeFileInput($event)">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

<button ion-button secondary (click)="openBrowser()">Open</button>
```

This is working on the browser as well as on IOS devices. But on android device. No any errors when debugging. Does anyone knows what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

The point is on the accept attribute of file input. 
You can try the following code.

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
```

If you want to restrict in specific file types, try the following example.

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```